# DQL inside custom repo

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

What am I doing wrong:

```
public function findAllVendorsByCategory ($categoryId)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $vendors = $em->createQueryBuilder('v')
      ->distinct()
      ->innerJoin('v.category', 'c')
      ->where('c.id = :category_id')
      ->setParameter('category_id', $categoryId)
      ->getQuery()
      ->iterate()
    ;

    return $vendors;
}
```

The error I am getting specifically is:

> No alias was set before invoking getRootAlias().

I have tried adding select() and nothing is working - this code worked fine when created in the context of the controller - but when I moved it into it's own repo - poof!?!

Thoughts?

EDIT | Latest attempt

```
    $vendors = $em->createQueryBuilder()
      ->distinct()
      ->from('Vendor', 'v')
      ->innerJoin('category', 'c', JOIN::ON, 'v.category_id = c.id')
      ->where('c.id = :category_id')
      ->setParameter('category_id', $categoryId)
      ->getQuery()
      ->iterate()
    ;
```

This produces DQL like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM Vendor v INNER JOIN category c ON v.category_id = c.id WHERE c.id = :category_id
```

But when I evaluate the DQL in bin/console or through app I get:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 16: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable
>   | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got
>   'FROM'

Comment: Have you registered the repositoryClass inside your Entity's `@Entity()` annotation?

Comment: Either use `$this->createQueryBuilder` (eg. the method from the repository) inside the repository or add the entity/table you want to select from using `->from(...)` when using the EntityManager-version of `createQueryBuilder`.

Comment: When selecting whole entities, groupBy is the way to go - you can only select distinct scalar values. What purpose has the distinct in your query? I suppose your IDs are unique?

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the `createQueryBuilder` method from the repository if you inherit from `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`:

Alias method from the Doctrine EntityRepository class:

```
/**
 * Creates a new QueryBuilder instance that is prepopulated for this entity name.
 *
 * @param string $alias
 * @param string $indexBy The index for the from.
 *
 * @return QueryBuilder
 */
public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)
{
    return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select($alias)
        ->from($this->_entityName, $alias, $indexBy);
}
```

So:

```
$vendors = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
  ->distinct()
  ->innerJoin('v.category', 'c')
  ->where('c.id = :category_id')
  ->setParameter('category_id', $categoryId)
  ->getQuery()
  ->iterate()
;
```

Alternatively, you can keep using the `createQueryBuilder` method from the EntityManager, but you need to add atleast the `->from` call (like the alias method does).

Comment: I assume that is how Symfony/Doctrine are handling the the repo's behind the scenes? At this point I would prefer the correct DQL calls.